# adding multiple scopes to nested eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

In my application users can predict scores of upcoming soccer games.

*Basically I want to display all the user predictions for this week. I do this by adding a scope to my match model that only loads matches from this week.*

**Problem: I'm still getting all my predictions from that user (not only the ones from the current week)** For predictions that my user created this week, the correct match is loaded. For the other predictions there is no match but they still get put in my query.

**How can I add another scope to my nested eager loading that will only select predictions made during this week or have a match that is not null?** (or other solution)

**Code:**

```php
public function showPredictions() {
    $user = auth()->user()->load(['predictions.match' => function ($query) { $query->thisWeek();}]);
    dd($user); 
    return view('predictions', compact('user'));
}
```

**Match model**

```php
public function Predictions() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Prediction', 'match_id', 'match_id');
}

public function scopeThisWeek($query) {
    $start_date = now()->previous(Carbon::TUESDAY);
    $end_date = now()->next(Carbon::MONDAY);
    return $query->whereDate('date','>', $start_date)->whereDate('date','<', $end_date);
}
```

**output**

```php
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "predictions" => Collection {#265 ▼
      #items: array:29 [▼
        0 => Prediction {#268 ▶}
        1 => Prediction {#269 ▶}
        2 => Prediction {#270 ▶}
        3 => Prediction {#271 ▶}
        4 => Prediction {#272 ▶}
        5 => Prediction {#273 ▶}
        6 => Prediction {#274 ▶}
        7 => Prediction {#275 ▶}
        8 => Prediction {#276 ▶}
        9 => Prediction {#277 ▶}
        10 => Prediction {#278 ▶}
        11 => Prediction {#279 ▶}
        12 => etc... 
      ]
```

**Output I want to achieve (I have 10 predictions for each user that week)**

```php
 #relations: array:1 [▼
    "predictions" => Collection {#265 ▼
      #items: array:10 [▼
        0 => Prediction {#268 ▶}
        1 => Prediction {#269 ▶}
        2 => Prediction {#270 ▶}
        3 => Prediction {#271 ▶}
        4 => Prediction {#272 ▶}
        5 => Prediction {#273 ▶}
        6 => Prediction {#274 ▶}
        7 => Prediction {#275 ▶}
        8 => Prediction {#276 ▶}
        9 => Prediction {#277 ▶}
        10 => Prediction {#278 ▶}
      ]
```

I have a relation field in my predictions array with the correct match in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `whereHas()`:

```php
$user = auth()->user()->load([
    'predictions' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('match', function ($query) {
            $query->thisWeek();
        });
    },
    'predictions.match'
]);
```

Comment: [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) is the documentation about `whereHas`.